# I need some help with idea's with my Blood Hunter Character!

Tags: dnd-5e, roleplaying

I am currently playing a Blood Hunter Character in my groups campaign, I have only been playing a D&D for about a year and i am still trying to be better at the Role Playing aspect. I know that with being a blood hunter they are always trying to find the balance of not crossing that line of becoming what they hunt I recently talked to my DM about exploring that side with my character crossing that line. I am currently playing 5th edition, I guess where i am stuck is how to go about role playing my character from going Neutral to Chaotic Neutral ( maybe almost slightly evil). The other part of it would be how would i do that in a way that i dont seem like a jerk to my other party members.

Comment: This requires at the very least the game you are playing. Even then, it might be pretty broad. Can you narrow down exactly where you are stuck? We really like questions that can have clear, concise answers. (Also, welcome to the site. Don't take it personally if your question gets put on hold; it's just a temporary thing to make sure your question is the best it can be, and the answers will be as helpful as they can be.)

Comment: (Also, there are many versions of D&D, so please add the version you are using)

Comment: I am currently playing 5th edition, I guess where i am stuck is how to go about role playing my character  from going  Neutral to Chaotic Neutral ( maybe almost slightly evil).  The other part  of it would be how would i do that in a way that i dont seem like a jerk to my other party members.

Comment: "What should I do?"-type questions are generally too broad to be answerable on RPG.SE. If you can find a more narrowly framed, ideally less subjective way to ask your question, it might be more appropriate for here.